# The Keyboard Freezes, App Crashes

Tags: cyanogenmod, keyboard, crashes, system-freeze

I'm running on CyanogenMod and in the middle of typing, the keyboard would freeze heavily and crash/minimize and I can't get it back up. This lasts for about a minute.

Comment: Which version? Did you flash the correct version of gapps for your version of CM? (Upgrading from 10.1.3 to 10.2, for example, without updating gapps, might well cause this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your screen blinks and/or keyboard freezes, go into

Settings --- > Developer options and make sure the following are checked. 
Disable HW Overlays and 
Force GPU Rendering

Now it should be blink/flash-freeze-free

Comment: Holy moly, so much smoother. Why is this not the default? Is battery consumption affected in any way?